# How can i find XElement using linq

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I m working with c#.

```
<Tüberkiloz>
    <Kod>
      1000
    </Kod>
  </Tüberkiloz>
  <Tifo>
    <Kod>
      1001
    </Kod>
  </Tifo>
  <Bakteriyel_Endokardit>
    <Kod>
      1002
    </Kod>
  </Bakteriyel_Endokardit>
```

this is my xml. And i wanna take Tifo. I must use "Kod" nodes.  e.g 
XpathSelectelement("Kod").value = 1001

Comment: Is this just an excerpt of your XML doc?  If not, you need a root element encompassing the whole document.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming every element has a `<Kod>` element, and they all contain valid integers, you could use:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(@"
    <root>
    <Tüberkiloz>
        <Kod>1000</Kod>
    </Tüberkiloz>
    <Tifo>
      <Kod>1001</Kod>
    </Tifo>
    <Bakteriyel_Endokardit>
      <Kod>1002</Kod>
    </Bakteriyel_Endokardit>
    </root>");

var matches = from el in doc.Root.Elements()
              where (int)(el.Element("Kod")) == 1001
              select el;
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
XElement root = XElement.Parse("...");
var tifo = (
    from kod in root.Descendants("Kod")
    where kod.Value == "1001"
    select kod.Parent
    ).First();
```

Comment: Try select kod instead of kod.Parent - still null? First() should throw an exception if the query didn't match anything, so I would be really surprised to see a null value returned...

Answer (score 0):

This will get you a collection of XElements that have matching values for the Kod element...

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(@"
                <root>
                <Tüberkiloz>
                    <Kod>1000</Kod>
                </Tüberkiloz>
                <Tifo>
                  <Kod>1001</Kod>
                </Tifo>
                <Bakteriyel_Endokardit>
                  <Kod>1002</Kod>
                </Bakteriyel_Endokardit>
                </root>");

var matchingElements = doc.XPathSelectElements("root/*[./Kod/text() = '1001']");
```

you can just use the value in the XPath statement, in this case 1001.  dahlbyk's answer and Thorarin's answer should both work as well (unless you have your value as an int already you don't need to cast, I would just compare it).

I just thought that I would post a simple one line solution to offer options.